# sp2013 online workflow email to external users doesnt include image

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

How can I send images to external users through send mail functionality in sp workflow?

I have a designer workflow that sends emails. I also have a multiple line of text field that contains a mix of text and image. When I try to send this data to A and B where B is an external user, only the text is received and a X mark is shown in the place of image. But to 'A' who is in the same domain, the image is visible. Is there a way I can embed the image into email and send it across to the external user?

Comment: Where are these images stored? You need to give the external users access to these images.

Comment: Hi Shashank. Thanks for you reply.  The items are stored in site assets.  By saying access, do you mean sharing of the site? Or do you propose to create a ID for external users in SP? right now sharing is disabled.

Comment: External sharing with anonymous access is what I thought, but I don't think that would work either, coz the URL for external users would be different. Sorry about that. The basic issue is because your external users are not authorized to view the images, so they see an X mark.

Comment: @ShashankReddyKaram is there a way we can pass credentials through javascript and download the images?